# reading through a file and printing line by line python

Tags: python

I have a file with different planets written on each line. I'm trying to iterate through it using the with function and print so the the output looks like this:

```
1 - mercury
2 - venus 
etc...
```

but my output currently looks like this:

```
(1, '-', <open file 'planets.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7f87dea69660>)
(2, '-', <open file 'planets.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7f87dea69660>)
(3, '-', <open file 'planets.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7f87dea69660>)
(4, '-', <open file 'planets.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7f87dea69660>)
```

my code is this:

```
with open("planets.txt") as p:
    i=0
    for line in p:
        i += 1
        print(i, '-', p)
```

How am I using with wrong or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing the `line` you print `p` - the file itself:

```
    print(i, '-', p)
```

Also, instead of making a new variable to count lines, you may use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) feature:

```
with open("planets.txt") as p:
    for i, line in enumerate(p, 1):
        print(i, '-', line)
```

**UPD:** You should also consider the fact, that the `line` you are getting from the file ends with a newline character and when you `print(line)` it adds another newline after it by defaulf. So your output will look like that:

```
1 - mercury

2 - venus 

etc...
```

to get

```
1 - mercury
2 - venus 
etc...
```

you need to specify `end=''` argument to print function. This way:

```
        print(i, '-', line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to print `line` not `p`:

```
with open("planets.txt") as p:
    i=0
    for line in p:
        i += 1
        print(i, '-', line) #refers to each line in p rather than the file handler
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `print(i, '-', p)` to `print(i, '-', line)`